# Converting map to KML/KMZ format and opening it on Google Earth?

Tags: kml, google-earth, kmz

How can I convert this map to KML/KMZ format and open it on Google Earth?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for having taken the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format. Please don't keep asking minor variants of the same question repeatedly.  Doing so will inevitably lead to them being closed as duplicates, and risks triggering an automated restriction on your ability to ask questions here.

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being an online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: Can we know which software you are using? What format your original data is in?

Answer (score 4):

Google Earth itself will give you an excellent georeferencing experience.

Go to menu `Add` and select `Image Overlay`. Select your image in the `Link` field (by clicking on <kbd>Browse</kbd> button).

You can control green handles on and around the image to fit it to desired location. Then hit <kbd>OK</kbd> to finish.

[image]

To save it as a new `kmz` file, go to `Places` panel and right click on the layer, then `Save Place As...`.